# "fatal: could not read Username for 'https://XXX': No such device or address" with drone.io and Gogs

Tags: git, drone.io, gogs

I want to use [drone.io](https://drone.io) and [gogs](https://gogs.io/) in order to have some CI features in my environment.

The documentation of [drone.io](https://drone.io) (http://docs.drone.io/) is not up-to-date, and I had to dig a lot in order to launch it.

My `docker-compose.yml` file is the following:

```
version: '3'

services:

  drone-server:
    image: drone/drone:latest
    network_mode: "bridge"
    volumes:
      - "/docker/drone:/var/lib/drone/"
    environment:
      - "DRONE_OPEN=true"
      - "DRONE_HOST=XXX"
      - "DRONE_SECRET=XXX"
      - "DRONE_GOGS=true"
      - "DRONE_GOGS_URL=http://gogs:3000"
      - "DRONE_GOGS_GIT_USERNAME=XXX"
      - "DRONE_GOGS_GIT_PASSWORD=XXX"
      - "DRONE_GOGS_PRIVATE_MODE=true"
    external_links:
      - "dedigogs_gogs_1:gogs"

  drone-agent:
    image: drone/agent:latest
    network_mode: "bridge"
    depends_on:
      - drone-server
    links:
      - drone-server
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
    environment:
      - "DRONE_SERVER=drone-server:9000"
      - "DRONE_HOST=XXX"
      - "DRONE_SECRET=XXX"
      - "DRONE_GOGS=true"
      - "DRONE_GOGS_URL=http://gogs:3000"
      - "DRONE_GOGS_GIT_USERNAME=XXX"
      - "DRONE_GOGS_GIT_PASSWORD=XXX"
      - "DRONE_GOGS_PRIVATE_MODE=true"
    external_links:
      - "dedigogs_gogs_1:gogs"
```

(`dedigogs_gogs_1` being my `gogs` docker instance)

I can connect to `drone` using my `gogs` credentials.

I can see all my private repositories, and enable them for `drone.io`.

However, when building a commit, the agent (I think) cannot clone the repository:

```
+ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /drone/src/XXX/XXX/XXX/.git/
+ git remote add origin https://XXX/XXX/XXX.git
+ git fetch --no-tags origin +refs/heads/master:
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://XXX': No such device or address
exit status 128
```

I tried playing with the `.drone.yml` (adding "`clone`" section, with `username`, `netrc.username`, ...), I also tried playing with environment variable, nothings work, I can't make `drone` authenticate for cloning repository.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the thing, I've had similar issues with gogs, for some reason the .netrc file is not matching with the url that uses to clone.

Try instead use the full url you use to access Gogs  in the browser instead of the internal hostname in the docker network

```
DRONE_GOGS_URL=http://myurl.to.gogs.com:3000
DRONE_GOGS_URL=http://some-ip-address:3000
```